After changing search URL cannot search special characters
From the default search URL https://example.com/?s=☏, any special characters or emojis can searched well.
But after changing the search URL using the bellow code...
function seo_search_result() {
    if ( is_search() && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/') === false && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/search/') === false ) {
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('home') . '/search/' . str_replace(' ', '-', str_replace('%20', '-', get_query_var('s'))));
        exit();
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'seo_search_result');

All results are good. But the following message appears when searching for special characters or emojis.
https://example.com/search/☏

Access to example.com was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
Reload

After changing the WordPress search URL, how do you show search results for special characters or emojis? Regards.
My search.php page includes the following code.
<?php
$search_query = urldecode(get_query_var('s'));
$args = array(
                's' =>$s
            );
    // The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );





if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        _e("<h2>Search Results for: ".get_query_var('s')."</h2>");
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
           $the_query->the_post();


        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;
        ?>

        <?php
        the_content( esc_html__( 'Continue reading &rarr;', 'arke' ) );
        }
    }else{
?>


        <h2>Nothing Found</h2>
          <p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p>
<?php } ?>

No work.

When you change the search URL in WordPress it will generate issues with special characters or emojis, it's often due to the way URLs are encoded.
Please make changes as per below shown. Let me know if it works!
URL Encoding
<?php
function seo_search_result() {
    if (is_search() && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/') === false && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/search/') === false) {
        $search_query = get_query_var('s');
        $encoded_query = urlencode($search_query); 
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('home') . '/search/' . str_replace(' ', '-', str_replace('%20', '-', $encoded_query)));
        exit();
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'seo_search_result');

On Search Results Page
<?php
$search_query = urldecode(get_query_var('s'));


I have updated search.php and function.php page but no work. Note that while search special characters, my search URL is always fine but no display any result yet. Look screenshot - https://ibb.co.com/QrY0kGX

May be my code is correct. You are facing 403 issue not related to my code

Is there no solution?
Note that if URL https://example.com/?s=☏ it works fine.
But if a custom URL, facing a problem.

Let me re check again tomorrow I'll get back you soon.
